# C - Matrix input function gets runtime error if matrix is bigger than 5x5, but there is no size defined at the code

Tags: c, matrix, malloc

I'm using this function to read the input matrix:

```
void leMatInt(int **M,int linhas,int colunas){
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < linhas; i++){
      for (j = 0; j < colunas; j++){
        scanf("%d", &M[i][j]);
        //printf("Leu [%d, %d]\n", i, j);
      }
    }
}
```

And I'm creating the matrix like this:

```
scanf("%d", &v1);
int **matriz1=(int **)malloc(v1 * sizeof(int));
for(i = 0;i < v1; i++){
    matriz1[i] = (int *)malloc(v1 * sizeof(int));
}
leMatInt(matriz1, v1, v1);
```

The code works nicely for v1 <= 4, but if I try to input a 5v5 matrix, the code gets runtime error at the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`matriz1` is a double pointer so while allocating memory you should write `sizeof(int*)`. because `** pointer` will holds/contains `* single` pointers.

```
int **matriz1 = malloc(v1 * sizeof(int*));
for(i = 0;i < v1; i++){
    matriz1[i] = malloc(v1 * sizeof(int));
}
```

typecasting `malloc()` is discouraged.

Answer (score 2):

```
int **matriz1=malloc(v1 * sizeof(int*));
```

A double (`**`) pointer variable will hold `pointer to an int`.

`matriz1` is a pointer to a pointer variable (pointer to a `int*`).

So it will contain `int*` variables.

Also casting the return type of `malloc` is unnecessary and check the return value of `malloc`.

It's undefined behavior here. That's why it works for `4` unexpectedly but doesn't work for `5x5` matrices.

---

> **An example: (Considering a particular case)**-
>
> Though `sizeof int` is implementation defined, but it's usually `4`
>   bytes. But sizeof pointer is usually `8` byte in 64-bit compiler.
>
> Now to hold 5 `int*` variable you need `40` byte. But you are allocating `20`
>   bytes. So you are allocating less memory than what you need. And
>   accessing memory that you are not permitted to, invoking undefined
>   behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
int **matriz1=(int **)malloc(v1 * sizeof(int));
```

This line is wrong. As already stated by other answers, the elements pointed to by `matriz1` are not integers but pointers to integers, so using `sizeof` with a type name should be `sizeof(int *)` here.

Also, casting the return value of `malloc()` is unnecessary and [arguably bad style](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2371524) in C.

To avoid errors like that, `sizeof` can also take an expression as an operand and uses the type this expression would evaluate to, which comes very handy with `malloc()` -- it should look like this:

```
int **matriz1 = malloc(v1 * sizeof *matriz1);
```

If you change the type of `matriz1` later, `sizeof *matriz1` still gives the correct element size -- it's the size of *whatever matriz1 points to*.